# Router's DHCP not working after a Windows machine is connected

Tags: router, dhcp

In my office, there are several computers that are connected to a router/access point.
Everything was fine until my wife came in with her laptop. It's on Windows 8.

Sometimes, other computers cannot connect to the Internet because the router's DHCP is not working. It never happened before.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: This problem can be solved by assigning specific ip address to specific mac address.

Comment: One possibility is that your wife's computer has statically assigned the router's IP address to itself. Another is that her computer has a DHCP server running.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My wife's computer works fine. Does that mean it's just normal?

Comment: @Ramhound You're right. But I want to avoid that and find another solution.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what would cause a computer to do that?  Let's suppose it was a cable modem or a PCI DSL modem, they don't do NAT.. I suppose the ISP does DHCP and the IP goes through the modem to the one device/computer connected. So even in that situation, the computer isn't looking at what the IP address is of another device and using it(the computer just takes what it got DHCPd). So what would cause it to look for the IP of another device - the router, and use that IP?

Comment: @barlop Almost every LAN that has multiple machines connected by WiFi uses NAT.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok and why would any take the ip of the router as their own ip?

Comment: @barlop There could be a lot of reasons. The most common -- if the router uses a common IP, like 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 and the PC was previously used as a router using the same common IP and the PC was never set back to use DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

The router may not have any more IP addresses to allocate. If you log into your routers `Admin Panel` (usually accessed by typing `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1` in any browser window).

If neither of the above addresses work, the information you need will be written somewhere on the router itself. Once you're logged into the `Admin Panel` you need to find the `DHCP settings` and check if there any available IP addresses. That information may not be provided so you may need to manually delete IP addresses that have been allocated, but are not currently in use.

Comment: The number of devices is only 5 or 6. I checked the router (192.168.1.254) already and DHCP status looks fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What does the laptop say when connecting?

Comment: Could not get IP address from DHCP...  something like that.

Comment: Hmmm. That usually points to what I stated above, but obviously that is not the case. Have you tried connecting any other devices?